# how to handle PDF after opening in my app swift

Tags: ios, pdf

My question, after I open PDF file with my app('register the document types that your application can open with iOS') I getting the files as NSCFString format)

Example:

```
let filemgr: NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();

        var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true);

        let documentsDirectory: String = paths[0] as! String

        let inboxPath: String = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Inbox");

        do
        {
            let dirFiles: [AnyObject] = try filemgr.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(inboxPath);
        }
        catch{}
```

My question is from this step I want to gather all this documents to one document and also open it with UIWebView. from what i read i need to find a way to convert it to nsdata or even draw it as PDF, but i really dont know how to handle it.

Thank you for help